# Is the fake animal at the start of "The Mermaid" supposed to be a Tasmanian Tiger?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-mermaid

At the start of the movie [The Mermaid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mermaid_(2016_film)) ([Chinese Wikipedia version](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%BE%8E%E4%BA%BA%E9%AD%9A_(2016%E5%B9%B4%E9%9B%BB%E5%BD%B1))), there's a animal that's supposed to be some exotic creature, but a member of the crowd visiting the museum points out that it's got a dog tag on saying that it's called "Lucky".

It looked like it was a [Tasmanian Tiger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thylacine) ([Chinese Wikipedia version](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A2%8B%E7%8B%BC)), but I couldn't tell, because the movie wasn't subtitled into English on the flight I was on. Trying to Google the movie's name plus Tasmanian Tiger didn't immediately get any relevant results.

The Tasmanian Tiger is one of the most famous extinct species in Australia - it's used as a symbol of Tasmania, and nowadays there are cryptozoologists still on the search for these creatures, just like people in other countries search for Bigfoot. However, I haven't noticed any interest in the creature outside of Australia. Was the fake animal at the start of "The Mermaid" supposed to be a Tasmanian Tiger?